# PJSIP record voice from mic only device to a wav file via conference bridge

Tags: audio, pjsip

I have a device which has mic (capture) only capability. I want to record the voice from that device to wav file.

When i do following step

```
wav = pjmedia_wav_writer_port_create
snd_port = pjmedia_snd_port_create_rec (NOTE: PJMEDIA_DIR_CAPTURE only)
pjmedia_snd_port_connect(snd_port , wav)
```

the voice is getting recorded into wav file

But when i do

```
wav = pjmedia_wav_writer_port_create
snd_port = pjmedia_snd_port_create_rec (NOTE: PJMEDIA_DIR_CAPTURE only)
conf = pjmedia_conf_create
pjmedia_snd_port_connect(snd_port , conf)
pjmedia_conf_add_port(conf, wav)
```

the voice is not getting recoded into wav file

i get following debug messages from pjmedia

```
sound:0     pjsip      80 samples reduced, buf_cnt=161
sound:0     pjsip      80 samples reduced, buf_cnt=161
sound:0     pjsip      80 samples reduced, buf_cnt=161
sound:0     pjsip      80 samples reduced, buf_cnt=161
sound:0     pjsip      80 samples reduced, buf_cnt=161
sound:0     pjsip      80 samples reduced, buf_cnt=161
```

Answer (score 1):

- I think you should not connect pjmedia_snd_port (microphone) to both wav file and conference bridge (directly).
- If you want to record to a file and using it in a conference bridge, It's better to connect sound device to a conference bridge and then create a rec port (pjmedia_port). Attach rec port to conference bridge and do some routing with pjmedia_conf_connect_port.
- Your debug message show because, if you want to using conference bridge, you have to connect it to a sound device with following function (pjmedia_snd_port_create or pjmedia_snd_port_create_player). Do not only connect microphone to conference bridge. Because conference bridge need some synchronization that use snd player to work.